# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: p

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium, I tried using implicit wait condition and wait until but it is of no use.But it is working fine when it is executed individually.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://runningstatus.in')
i=0

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
select=Select(browser.find_element_by_id('godate'))
select.select_by_index(i)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys('12801',Keys.RETURN)

x=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.runningstatus-widget-content')
name=x.find_element_by_tag_name('p')

print name.text
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Any time a page transition occurs, or a new element is expected to appear, you should wait for it to exist in the DOM. If you don't, you'll get frequent timeouts. In your case, try the following...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://runningstatus.in')
i=0

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
select=Select(browser.find_element_by_id('godate'))
select.select_by_index(i)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys('12801',Keys.RETURN)

css = 'div.runningstatus-widget-content'
x = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(('css selector', css)))

print x.text
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ron Norris

Comment: Still, it is showing the same error.When i tried this,  name=x.find_element_by_tag_name('p')

Comment: Not sure then why it's not working for you. This worked on my system all the way through the print statement. This was my command line output: `Live Running Train Status` and
`Enter Train Number:`

Comment: But i want to access the p tag,and that is returning an error.

Comment: The short answer is that the x element has no <p> children. So in your original code, `name=x.find_element_by_tag_name('p')` will throw an exception because there are no <p> elements within x. So I believe the selector you're using to find x is not what you really want. Looking for the <p> tag is the correct process, if x had a <p> element.